# How to store the wchar value in double quotes string

Tags: c++, c

**in the below code i am getting the c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.057 to the  buffer.Now i wnat to store the above value in doble quotes " c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.057" and i want to pass this for the process. how to make this path in double quotes....**

```
  HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mscoree.dll"));
  FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR   GetCORSystemDirectory = NULL;
GetCORSystemDirectory = (FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR) GetProcAddress   (hDLL,"GetCORSystemDirectory"); 
if(GetCORSystemDirectory!=NULL)
          {      
             WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];
             DWORD length; 
             HRESULT hr = GetCORSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH,&length);
             std::string tbuf="\"buffer\"";
             // std::string tbuf=" \""+(string)buffer+"\\InMageSQL.dll\" /codebase /tlb /silent";

             if(S_OK==hr)
             {
                wcscat( buffer,L"RegAsm.exe" );
                STARTUPINFO si;
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
                si.cb = sizeof(si);
                ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );  //(LPSTR)getcurrentpath.c_str()
                if(!CreateProcess((LPCTSTR)buffer,(LPTSTR)strInMageSqlDll.c_str(),NULL, NULL,FALSE, 0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi ) )
                {
                  cout<<"CreateProcess failed "<<GetLastError()<<endl;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here, since I haven't used much of the Windows API in recent years and I never used `WCHAR`.

For one, you could widen the buffer a bit and poke the quotes right into it:

```
WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH + 1 + 2];
buffer[0] = L'"';
buffer[sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(WCHAR)-1] = L'"';
DWORD length; 
HRESULT hr = GetCORSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH+1,&length);
```

However, this seems inelegant at best. (And I'd need to think twice whether I got that `sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(WCHAR)-1` right -- which I'm too lazy for.)

Another way would be to use the `std::basic_string<>` template. Note that `std::string` is a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<char>` . There's little preventing you from instantiating it for other character types, too:

```
WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];
DWORD length; 
HRESULT hr = GetCORSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH,&length);
std::basic_string<WCHAR> tbuf= L"\"" + buffer + L"\"";
// use 'tbuf.c_str()' to read 'tbuf' as a C-string (there's no safe way to write to it)
```

Note that this presumes that `WCHAR` expands to `wchar_t`. If this isn't the case (I have never worked with it, so I wouldn't know), you'd have to cast the literals:

```
std::basic_string<WCHAR> tbuf = static_cast<WCHAR>(L'"')
                              + buffer 
                              + static_cast<WCHAR>(L'"');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
std::wstring tbuf="\"";
tbuf+= buffer;
tbuf+= "\"";
```

Comment: You can't append wchar_t strings to basic_string<char>

Comment: @JaredPar: But you can't assign a `const char[]` to a `std::wstring` either.

Answer (score -1):

JaredPar's method works, here is one alternative:

```
std::wostringstream oss
oss << '"' << buffer << '"';
std::wstring strBuff(oss.str());
```

**edit:**

switched to the w* versions.

Comment: Made the same mistake.  Using wostringstream and wstring should work just fine.

Comment: @luke: It has, however, the disadvantage of constructing and destructing a string stream for an operation that could easily (and likely cheaper) be done using solely strings.

Comment: It's just one alternative.  The situation doesn't seem to be a grave performance concern.